# How does OpenMP provide pragma functions?

Tags: c++, openmp, preprocessor, pragma

I've very curious, OpenMP provides pragma functions like `#pragma omp parallel`. How does it provide it?

Comment: A compiler that understands OpenMP sees them and does the appropriate things when generating code.

Comment: The compiler itself provides the pragma, not the library.

Comment: Pragmas are not functions. There are a mean to "explain" to the compiler what does the code and what you want. The compiler will generate and parallelize code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at https://www.dontknow.de/openmp-stuff/ on my website.  It provides a short introduction about how OpenMP compilers work.  It should answer the most basic questions about the code transformations and interactions with a lower-level threading library.

The basic idea is that code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    printf(“Hello World\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

is transformed like this:

```
void main_omp_func_0() {
    printf(“Hello World\n”);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    _omp_start_parallel_region(main_omp_func_0);
    main_omp_func_0();
    _omp_end_parallel_region();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler will have to do a bit more if data needs to be passed to the parallel region, e.g., when using `shared`, `private`, etc. variables.  These are then passed as pointers to the original variables in the global data and/or the stack of the master thread.

Comment: It would be great if you could give a quick summary of the topic - with the link for further information.